# Excel Macro to print Hyperlinked word documents

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I'm trying to create a macro to print all hyperlinked word documents on an active spreadsheet.

Cells A1:A200 contain hyperlinks. I want to open a hidden Word application - check cell A1 for hyper link - if present open link - print document - close document - move to next cell A2 - Check for hyperlink in A2 etc... close hidden word application at the end. If the cell contains no hyperlink move to the next cell with out any error.

I've toyed around and I'm not getting very far so I'm hoping someone will be able to help me out.

Not all documents are word some are open office .ods files so if I could open the hyperlink and print with the native program then close that would be even better but I'm happy to convert all .ods to .doc to make it work if easier.

Thanks!

Edit: This code will only print random links not all.

```
Sub ExportToWordAndPrint()

Const Ttl As String = "Word Print"
Dim cell As Range, rng As Range
Dim FullNameOfFile As String
Dim WordApp As Object, MyDoc As Object

On Error Resume Next
    Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

If WordApp Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Microsoft Word is not installed on this computer - operation cancelled.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, Ttl
    Exit Sub
End If

WordApp.Visible = False
Set rng = Selection

For Each cell In rng

    On Error Resume Next
        FullNameOfFile = ""
        FullNameOfFile = cell.Hyperlinks(1).Address
    On Error GoTo 0

    If FullNameOfFile <> "" Then 'cell may not have contained a Hyperlink

        If Dir(FullNameOfFile) <> "" Then 'cell may contain a Hyperlink, but the file itself may not exist

            With WordApp
                Set MyDoc = .documents.Open(Filename:=FullNameOfFile)
                MyDoc.PrintOut
                .ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With

        End If

    End If

Next cell

Set WordApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Edit to Code to input debug line. The two End If lines have been deleted above Next Cell to avoid a compile error.

```
Sub ExportToWordAndPrint()

Const Ttl As String = "Word Print"
Dim cell As Range, rng As Range
Dim FullNameOfFile As String
Dim WordApp As Object, MyDoc As Object

On Error Resume Next
    Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

If WordApp Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Microsoft Word is not installed on this computer - operation cancelled.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, Ttl
    Exit Sub
End If

WordApp.Visible = False
Set rng = Selection

For Each cell In rng

    On Error Resume Next
        FullNameOfFile = ""
        FullNameOfFile = cell.Hyperlinks(1).Address
    On Error GoTo 0

    If FullNameOfFile <> "" Then Debug.Print cell.Address & " failed, appears to have no hyperlink"

        If Dir(FullNameOfFile) <> "" Then Debug.Print cell.Address & " failed, appears to have wrong filename"

                Debug.Print cell.Address & " should print"

            With WordApp
                Set MyDoc = .documents.Open(Filename:=FullNameOfFile)
                MyDoc.PrintOut
                .ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With

    Next cell

Set WordApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

The first link is now printing only not the rest. Is the problem that I haven't selected a range? Not sure where to put this in?

Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: @GaryMcParland - You can generate more information for yourself by inserting some `debug.print` lines. 1) Put an else condition for `If FullNameOfFile <> "" Then`. After the else put `Debug.print cell.address & " failed, appears to have no hyperlink" ` 2) Put an else condition for `If Dir(FullNameOfFile) <> "" Then`. After the else put `Debug.print cell.address & " failed, appears to have wrong filename"` 3) Before `With WordApp`, put `Debug.print cell.address & " should print"` The output will appear in the immediate window of the VB Editor. This should help pinpoint what your issues are.

Comment: I'll give this a try. I'm new to this but I think I follow what you mean

Answer (score 0):

So as I understand from your post, the DOC files print okay.

An approach you can use to print the ODS documents is to use the command line to get OpenOffice to print the document. As shown on this site:
https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/FAQ/General/Is_there_a_way_to_print_a_batch_of_files_without_opening_each_of_them_in_OOo%3F

```
OfficeID = Shell "openoffice -pt ""PRINTER-NAME"" FILENAME"
```

If the application does not exit after it finishes, you can use the OfficeID to terminate the process. For example with `Shell "TASKKILL /PID " & CStr(OfficeID)`.

Note: I have not tried this myself, but should get you started.

**Update**

Here is the code that I tried to edit but some reviewers who did not read the post reverted it, this is why you did not see it, this is the correct way to add the `Debug` lines:

```
Sub ExportToWordAndPrint()

Const Ttl As String = "Word Print"
Dim cell As Range, rng As Range
Dim FullNameOfFile As String
Dim WordApp As Object, MyDoc As Object

On Error Resume Next
    Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

If WordApp Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Microsoft Word is not installed on this computer - operation cancelled.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, Ttl
    Exit Sub
End If

WordApp.Visible = False
Set rng = Range("A4:A200")

For Each cell In rng

    On Error Resume Next
        FullNameOfFile = ""
        FullNameOfFile = cell.Hyperlinks(1).Address
    On Error GoTo 0

    If FullNameOfFile <> "" Then 'cell may not have contained a Hyperlink

        If Dir(FullNameOfFile) <> "" Then 'cell may contain a Hyperlink, but the file itself may not exist

            'Debug.print cell.address & " should print"    'THIS ONE ADDED
            With WordApp
                Set MyDoc = .documents.Open(Filename:=FullNameOfFile)
                MyDoc.PrintOut
                .ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With
        Else         'THIS ONE ADDED
            'Debug.print cell.address & " failed, appears to have wrong filename" 
        End If
    Else             'THIS ONE ADDED
        'Debug.print cell.address & " failed, appears to have no hyperlink"    
    End If

Next cell

WordApp.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
Set WordApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: No the word docs don't print okay, if I have 10 links for example only 2 might print... Not even the first 2. I might get 2 and 4 printing or sometimes I'll only get one printing in total

Comment: OK. Are those links are actually correct? Did you try to open them manually? And let us know what is the outcome of the `Debug.Print` texts so we know why don't they print. Your code is correct so if the file data in the links are correct, then they should print. One reason that occured to me if the links have URL encoding such as `%20` instead of `" "`. This would be a reason for not being able to open the file.

Comment: The links are to local word documents located in the same folder as the excel workbook. I've tried to put the debug lines in but I'm clearly not doing it right I just keep getting errors... I'm still in the learning phase with this. Any further help would be very much appreciated. I can upload the file with the macro in place some where if that would help

Comment: One other thing I've noticed is the word files need to be in .doc as it won't recognise .docx format

Comment: I cant see it? The last edit I can see was by Om3r 6 hours ago?

Comment: I've added in the debug lines and its not giving errors any more. I had to delete the last two End If lines at the end to avoid a compile error. But, its now only printing the first link. After the first link it stops? what do i need to do to make it keep searching to the end of the document?

Comment: Ok. I've added in the code you edited with the debug lines. Thanks you I now understand what you meant. When I run the Macro I still get the same this it only prints one file not them all. I have discovered it only prints the file when I have the cell selected so that is why it was printing random files and not them all because I had say the second or third cell selected so it was sending that one to the printer. The code isn't cycling onto the next file then the next until it finds empty cells - Is there a way to incorporate this?

Comment: I've uploaded a sample sheet to dropbox with the Macro enabled. If you link a few word documents to the 'View Map' text then select the 'Print All Maps' button it will execute the macro and you may see what I mean. Thanks again for all your help on here so far! link below: https://www.dropbox.com/s/oht7hl8di07nwfh/Macro%20Test.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: Alright. I see your macro and the document. Right now the way you have it is that it cycles through the selected cells. What is exactly that you want to achieve? This is where you set where the macro is looking and these are the cells it loops through: `Set rng = Selection` See my code, updated, this now has `Set rng = Range("A4:A200")` and this will loop through all the cells in this range, regardless of selection.

Comment: Getting somewhere!! So if the range is left at Selection and I highlight the A column it works perfectly. I'd like it to work without having to select the A column... When I change rng = Range("A4:A200") I get an automation error: Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)': Automation Error the object invoked has disconnected from its clients. When I select debug it highlights 'MyDoc.PrintOut' which is just above the line '.ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=False'

Comment: Ok, let's see. First, let's delete some of this comments as it is hard to see where we are at. It seems that this error message relates to the actual file, not the rest of the code. You could change the `WordApp.Visible = False` to `True` for the time being and see what takes place when the error happens. You could change the line to `Set rng=Range("A:A")` though I don't think that is directly contributing to the error you just wrote.

Comment: Ive set the range to A1:A100 and set wordapp.Visible = True and its working perfectly!! You my friend have been fantastic help, it was really bugging me!! The only thing is the word application stays open after printing although its minimised so its not a big issue. Thanks Again!!!

Comment: Great. I am glad, don't forget to accept the answer and upvote it if it helped you. On Word staying open, the you can add this line before the `Set WordApp = Nothing` line to close Word: `WordApp.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges` I also added this to the code above. Also you should comment out the `Debug` lines so they are not executed every time, they are for debug purposes only.